# Resolving many Backbone dependencies with jQuery Deferred objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've got a fairly sizable Backbone.js project, so I'm looking to lazy load as many resources as possible.

Consider a view that needs to load it's own template, some templates for subviews, and a collection. (I don't want to have to wait for every async dependency to resolve before requesting the next one.) It would be helpful if I could do something like...

```
initialize: function() {

  $.when([
    Handlebars.get('Template1', callback),         // callback sets this.template
    Handlebars.get('Template2', callback),        // callback sets subview template
    App.Store.get('MessageCollection', callback) // callback sets this.collection
  ]).then($.proxy(this.render, this));          // render
}
```

Where the `get` functions are some helpers I've built that serve up the resource if it exists in cache/storage, otherwise it'll return the deferred object...

```
return $.ajax(...)
```

So these `get` helpers need to return a jquery deferred object no matter what. Are there any problems with returning a resolved deferred object when the resource is found in cache/storage?

```
App.Store.get = function(resource, callback) {

  if (resource exists) {
    return $.Deferred().done(callback).resolve();
  } else {
    var model = new App.Model;
    return model.fetch();
  }
}
```

Would this cause any problems? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with that. Though, if you store the actual deferred object in the cache, you could just return the old already resolved deferred object rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I thought about that, but I would need to `deferred.reject().done(callback).resolve()`. Think there would any performance gains?

Comment: you can't reject it then resolve it. Once it's rejected, it can't be resolved or rejected again.

Comment: I was thinking I would need to update the `done` callback, but I can just call the callback myself. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your approach should work as is.
You could use [jquery.whenall](https://github.com/Zenovations/jQuery-whenAll) plugin in order to wait for multiple requests in parallel.

But if the project is actually more complex than just several templates to load, you probably should look at some AMD solution like [require.js](http://www.requirejs.org/)

Comment: I figured I would get a require.js answer. It just seems so invasive to the codebase. I'll look into it again.

Comment: What's the difference in jQuery's `when` and the `whenall` plugin?

Comment: jquery's when will return immediately if something fails, while whenall will wait till they all complete before it returns regardless of whether or not one fails.

Comment: I won't be using require.js because I need the script to run before dependencies are loaded. That way the view can display a loading animation and the UI seems snappier.

Comment: It's still possible with require. You can first run some initial code and then call require: require(dependencies, function () { <your code when deps loaded> })

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the old deferred object in the cache directly, you could just return it as-is.

```
var cache = {};

App.Store.get = function(resource, callback) {

  if (cache[resource]) {
    return cache[resource].done(callback);
  } else {
    return cache[resource] = new App.Model.fetch().done(callback); // assuming this returns a deferred obj
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes it difficult to grab the returned data, the callback is proxied for one and wouldn't even be called in subsequent `get`s.